# Ubuntu 17.04 - Color Calibration - Device set as uncalibrated

Tags: monitor

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu today and it seems I can't calibrate the display.

Any idea on how this thing works?
I'm using a Lenovo laptop with built-in display.

[image: ubuntu color calibration]

Answer (score 1):

Dorian, I had two prior Lenovo laptops, and the ThinkWiki was extremely useful to me. For color calibration, [review this page](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Colour_profile).

In the end, you'll want to install the ICM file on your laptop.

Comment: Thank you but I have an IdeaPad, not a ThinkPad...

Comment: Both of my Lenovos were IdeaPads (a z510 and a u300s) as well. The ThinkWiki can still be a very useful resource.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. It seems my laptop monitor is not being identified by using "sudo get-edid | parse-edid" or "monitor-edid". And I can't seem to be able to extract files from the 1yoi04ww.exe